How do we know that at the Schwarzschild radius the falling speed is $c$?
I see something strange: The kinetic energy required for a falling body to reach the Schwarzschild radius is $(\gamma-1)mc^{2}$, so with $\gamma$ tending to infinity at the Schwarzschild radius, the kinetic energy becomes infinite, and even greater beyond that, which doesn't make sense....
So, how do we know that at the Schwarzschild radius the falling speed of a free falling body from infinity is $c$? Why don't we assume instead that the falling speed tends towards $c$ without ever reaching it, and that the formation of a black hole is impossible because it would require infinite energy?"

This question is similar to: Will free-fall object into black hole exceed speed of light $c$ before hitting black hole surface?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your answer is that we do say the falling speed tends towards $c$. It reaches $c$ at the EH, and that’s okay because the event horizon can’t ever actually be reached. There are specific metrics that allow for black hole formation, and of course we have observed black holes directly, so.

@ user419029 your edits don't actually address the distinction between your question and the previous one. If your question was not answered by the one from 12 years ago, what is different in your question? E.g. maybe you are more interested in energy than in speed. So you can edit your question to focus less on the speed and more on the energy. IMO, the speed part was answered by the previous question, but not the energy part. Since speed and energy are related, it may seem to others that answering the speed part also answers the energy part, so you should identify the distinction you need

The total conserved energy in the Schwarzschild spacetime is a sum of kinetic and internal: $E=K+mc^2$. Assuming a fall from rest, at infinity: $K=0$, $E=m_oc^2$ where $m_o$ is the rest mass. During the fall the kinetic energy increases at the expense of the decreasing mass (the mass defect). The total energy remains the same per energy conservation. At the horizon the mass tends to zero, so the kinetic energy equals the total energy: $m\to 0$, $E=K=m_oc^2$. Note that there is no “potential energy” in General Relativity, it does not exist. So there is no “infinite energy” you are referring to.

The mass of a geodesic particle is constant along the geodesic.

@safesphere : Can you give a reference about this ? I don't think it's true. There is no such mass defect. Only gravitational waves energy can decrease the mass of a falling body, the kinetic part is added to the mass.

@ controlgroup. What you're saying is not true, the event horizon can be reached. The decrease in speed is only an coordinates artefact. In the falling body reference frame there is not such decrease.

The other question did not have a proper answer, it states : " If you use coordinates that are co-moving with the rock falling into the black hole then the rock will see the event horizon pass at the speed of light." So objects on this event horizon have infinite energy

@user419029 You are referring to the rest mass, which is measured in the rest frame of the object and is always the same. However, as measured remotely, mass in GR depends on coordinates. For example, the mass of light in a weightless mirror box is $m=E/c^2$ where $E$ is the energy of the light that depends on coordinates and on the time dilation. So mass is not constant at all. Furthermore, if "the kinetic part is added to the mass", then energy conservation would be violated, as I already explained (here is no potential energy in GR), but energy is conserved in the Schwarzschild spacetime.

@user419029 The beauty of GR is that there is no gravitational energy. A body does not gain any energy during the fall, but simply moves on inertia along its geodesic. "Potential gravitational energy" is a purely Newtonian construct that does not reflect the reality, but is made up to be able to explain things. For example, per Newton, when two masses $M$ and $m$ fall onto each other from rest at infinity and collide, the collision energy is in addition to $M+m$. However, in GR, the total resulting energy, including the collision energy, is exactly $M+m$. No extra energy is gained in the fall.

@safesphere When the falling body follows its geodesic it does not receive energy from the outside but when it falls on the ground in addition to its mass energy it has a potential energy that does not contribute to the mass but is physical and is a binding energy. The proof is that to escape the attraction it is necessary to provide a kinetic energy equal to this potential energy.

@user419029 Your post refers to the Newtonian gravity. There is no “potential energy” in General Relativity. I’ve stated this already 3 times with examples, but you don’t seem to be receptive to new information. With this approach you are not looking for the correct answer, but for the answer matching your view. “to escape the attraction it is necessary to provide a kinetic energy” - The logical flaw here is in using a different frame. You measure this energy on top of the rest mass locally. These values are redshifted in remote coordinates where the total energy always equals the rest mass.

@safesphere You claim to know the correct answer, and I doubt it. It is not because the theory does not speak of energy that there is no energy. Factually gravitational potential energy exists, it is an absolute fact. On the other hand, general relativity is a mathematical abstraction, so that it does not use potential energy as such simply proves that it is only a map and not the territory. What matters is what happens on the surface not what can be measured from another point of view.

@safesphere Nevettheless the question I asked is not whether potential energy exists or not. My question is: why did we keep Newton's acceleration in the GR equations instead of substituting an acceleration that tends towards c without ever reaching it?

@user419029 No, you did not mention acceleration in your question. Your question starts and ends with "infinite kinetic energy" while the total energy doesn't change. Instead of asking a focused question, you are making incorrect assumptions and wrong conclusions in the same sentence: "Why don't we assume instead that the falling speed tends towards $c$ without ever reaching it..." - Here you assume that we don't, but we do. Then you conclude: "... and that the formation of a black hole is impossible because it would require infinite energy?" - Which is wrong as explained more than once.

@user419029 Here is a conceptual picture of a star collapse (with simplifying assumptions). The initial mass of the star matter is $M$, its initial kinetic energy $K$ is zero. In the collapse, the matter accelerates to nearly the speed of light, but never reaches it in our remote coordinates. The mass of the star matter tends to zero due to the mass defect. Its kinetic energy tends to $K=Mc^2$. The total energy $E$ is conserved. The mass of the resulting black hole is $E/c^2=Mc^2/c^2=M$. The mass of the black hole is the same as the mass of the original star, assuming no emission or radiation.
